# track changes of nodes bound in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I need to track changes in absolute position and size of a node in javafx.Any change that is caused by resizing window or user manipulation,...

```
 node.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {

 @Override
 public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observable,Bounds oldValue, Bounds newValue) {

 System.err.println("Changed!");


 }

 });


 node.boundsInParentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {

 @Override
 public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observable,Bounds oldValue, Bounds newValue) {

 System.err.println("Changed!");


 }

 });
```

I tried these solutions but doesn't work!

please help me, thanks.

Comment: Have You tried keeping the references to your ChangeListeners? I had an issue once, where the Garbage Collector would remove them. Internally, the bindings are realized with WeakReferences.

Comment: no, I did not keep the references.How should I do that? Can I keep them in a list only?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite heavy on performance, so I do not recommend doing this with a large number of nodes in the scene graph, but:

```
ObjectBinding<Bounds> boundsInScene = Bindings.createObjectBinding(
    () -> node.localToScene(node.getBoundsInLocal()),
    node.localToSceneTransformProperty(),
    node.boundsInLocalProperty());

boundsInScene.addListener((obs, oldBounds, newBounds) -> 
    System.err.println("Changed!"));
```

You can also do the following, which might be less prone to premature garbage collection:

```
ChangeListener<Object> listener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
    System.err.println("New bounds in scene: "+node.localToScene(node.getBoundsInLocal()));
node.localToSceneTransformProperty().addListener(listener);
node.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener(listener);
```

Comment: unfortunately, I have a large number of node in the scene graph.. do you have a better solution that doesn't have heavy effect on performance?

Comment: Keeping track of this will necessarily be performance-intensive, no matter how you do it. The issue is that you really need to track everything in the scene graph from the node up to the root. I recommend you try this and see if the performance is adversely affected. Other than that, you might want to consider if you can avoid needing to do this at all.

Comment: @James_D I want the same thing...I have a class and in that class I create a rectangle next to the some nodes...I added this binding for each node and instead of System.err.print I added a method to  set location of rectangle according to newBounds....But this method is called just one time! instead, I should create an object of that class each time...so it works correctly and very slow and program will hang....can you help me ?